# Where are the addresses of local and other variable types stored?

Tags: c++, c, variables, memory-address

I was asked this question and I am not quite sure about the answer. I know that the value (content) of local variables is on the stack and those allocated on heap (in C/C++ language). But:

1- Where are the addresses of those local variables stored? How the program knows where on the stack it should look for each of the local variables? Are these references (addresses of each variable) saved on data segment? How about the address of other variable types (global, pointer, ...)

2- Am I right that programs directly (not using pop/push) read/write to different addresses in stack segment when dealing with local variables?

Comment: The answer to (1) is essentially 'in the instructions'. (2) Yes, via stack pointer offsets.

Comment: The *address* of a local variable isn't stored anywhere, unless you have a pointer pointing to the local variable. The local variables themselves are typically stored on the stack on most modern systems. And the compiler doesn't really push or pop the single variables to/from the stack, it simply reserves enough space and uses offsets.

Comment: At compile-time the compiler decides where everything is going to be, and translates the program into assembly instructions that refer to those memory locations it decided on

Comment: You're falling into chicked-and-egg logic here. If the addresses of local variables are stored n imemory, then those addresses have an address too. Where are the addresses of addresses stored? And where are the addresses of addresses of addresses etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The compiler will track where, relative to the top of the stack, each argument and local variable is located. And if possible, the compiler will use registers for "important" variables (such as loop counters) - it will use statistics of how many times each variable is used to see which ones are "hot" (used a lot) and which are "cold" (not used much).

   Note that "addresses of local variables" doesn't always apply. Registers have no (direct) address [except in the TI TMS9900 processor and a few others, where registers and memory have slightly blurred lines].

   The compiler will know where each of the things are - it's what compilers do - just like it knows WHICH variable has been stored where in the data section. Exactly how this is done is the subject of a small book. For now, just trust that the compiler does this.
2. Yes, nearly all processors today allow reads and writes from stack + offset (where offset is typically negative, so further down the stack, as the stack normally grows towards zero).

   Although the stack sometimes counts as the "data segment", it's typically its own section of memory on modern machines - and if you have multiple threads, each thread will have its own stack.

Comment: in the PIC microcontroller there are no register (except W) but register files, so all RAM can be addressed as a register

Answer (score 1):

First, for the protocol, let's just note that the answers to both questions are subjected to compiler implementation and are not dictated by the language standard (nor C neither C++).

---

> Where are the addresses of those local variables stored?

The symbols (names of functions and variables) are translated into addresses **during compilation**, i.e., they are not stored anywhere in the memory of the executed program:

- Addresses of functions are in the code-segment of the executable image

  They are constant throughout the execution of the program
- Addresses of static and/or global variables are in the data-segment of the executable image

  They are constant throughout the execution of the program
- Addresses of non-static local variables are in the stack of the executable image

  They may be different each time the function where these variables are declared is invoked

---

> Am I right that programs directly (not using pop/push) read/write to different addresses in stack segment when dealing with local variables?

Depends on your platform (underlying HW architecture + designated compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Re #2: "the stack" is of [*stack frames*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#STACK-FRAME), not separate local variables.  While individual values are sometimes pushed and popped (*e.g.*, return addresses), local variables are normally created all at once by simply adjusting the stack pointer.  That "creates" an area on the stack without storing any particular values there (which is why uninitialized variables might have any value), and then offsets from the stack pointer are used to find the individual variables.

See also [a similar CS SE question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/76871/how-are-variables-stored-in-and-retrieved-from-the-program-stack).